# How do I save values of forms to be edited later in case user clicks on back button?

Tags: reactjs

So I have this page, the sidebar has 3 options. In step 1, the user enters data and click and save and next, in step 2 there are few more fields, he again clicks save and next and in step 3, he previews it saves it. In case the user wants to edit data, he can click on step 1 or 2 and change data. How do i save the data to be edited later?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knqb6.png)

Comment: you can try localStorage for this

Comment: why not save the data from the forms in your `state`?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data with 3 methods-

1. Use localStorage

if you are using a json object then you can use localStorage.setItem("data123",JSON.stringify(data))

and fetch the data using JSON.prase(localStorage.getItem("data123"))

2. sessionStorgae

Syntax is same as localStaorage. Just replace localwith session

Difference - local is persistent, session get deleted when page is closed.

3. React state (prefered method if persistent storage is not required)

You can use useState hook (for functional component) or state = {} (for classful components).

Usage and examples are readily available one search away.

Note: Is using React states and the component which taken in the input data is inside a parent component the define the states in parent and pass the hook definitions to the child component or else when the component changes, the hooks will be lost if defined in the child component

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to save form data locally is to preserve it in your form handler class like you can create a new Handler class and create setter and getter in it which store the form fields data/values in object key, value pair which you always update whenever fields update.